# Wordpress Plugin Ajax get Javascript Array Data into PHP Variable

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

```
function my_action_javascript($val1, $val2) { 
  ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var data = {
            'email': '<?php echo $val1?>',
            'password': '<?php echo $val2?>'
    };

    jQuery.post({
      url: 'dummyurl',
      method: "POST",
      data: data,
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    })
  });
    </script>
<?php
}
```

I got this function in my Wordpress Plugin. I parse in some data in the function and then i do a ajax request in Javascript. That all works just fine and i get the data array as response.

The Question is, how do i get the data from the Array in Javascript into my Variable in PHP so i can put the Data into my Wordpress Options?

Comment: can you post your array of response?

Comment: you can get `$email = $_POST['email'];`

Comment: {somedata: "datahere", moredata: "data", moredata: 66, data: null, bool: true}

Comment: ajax url is `admin ajax`?

Comment: sry i dont meant the $_POST, i mean the data i get from the success function of the AJAX Call

Comment: no the url is from a external REST API

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

you need to parse the response.

```
function my_action_javascript($val1, $val2) { 
  ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var data = {
        'email': '<?php echo $val1?>',
        'password': '<?php echo $val2?>'
    };

    jQuery.post({
      url: 'dummyurl',
      method: "POST",
      data: data,
      success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( data);

    console.log(obj.somedata);
      }
    })
  });
    </script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: I dont know if this is the solution, my question is how can i use my response in one other php function?

Comment: you cannot assign javascript variable to php variable

Comment: you can use curl post instead of ajax

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a PHP script that gets called by the AJAX request that will write the data into your options table. There's a specific way of doing this with Wordpress: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

In a nutshell, you need to add an `action` parameter to your POST data and then hook your PHP callback function to this parameter. In your callback, you can then use `update_option()`.